# I can not query attributes with xpath in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

The simplest example w3c page does not work in firefox but if it works in Chrome.
Selecting xpath attributes:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>

function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
try {xhttp.responseType="msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp;
}

var x=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");
var xml=x.responseXML;
path="/bookstore/book/title/lang/@lang";

// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType=="msxml-document")
{
xml.setProperty("SelectionLanguage","XPath");
nodes=xml.selectNodes(path);
for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
  {
  document.write(nodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("<br>");
  }
}

// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
{
var nodes=xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var result=nodes.iterateNext();

while (result)
  {
  document.write(result.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("<br>");
  result=nodes.iterateNext();
  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Xpath expression as you can see is:

```
path="/bookstore/book/title/lang/@lang"
```

I do not get it to work in Firefox but if it works on Google Chrome, Opera and Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)` as a check to use the `evaluate` method, if you want to use a method then check for that method and not for other, unrelated objects.

So a check

```
if (typeof xml.evaluate != 'undefined') {
  var xpathResult = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
  var node;
  wile ((node = xpathResult.iterateNext()) != null) {
   document.write(node.nodeValue);
  }
}
```

should do. Your XPath selects attribute nodes so simply access the nodeValue of that attribute, I don't understand why you think it has a child node to access.

```js
var xmlSource = [
  '<bookstore>',

'<book category="COOKING">',
  '<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>',
  '<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>',
  '<year>2005</year>',
  '<price>30.00</price>',
'</book>',

'</bookstore>'
  ].join('\n');

var xmlDoc;

if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined') {
  xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlSource, 'application/xml');
  }

var path="/bookstore/book/title/@lang";

if (typeof xmlDoc.evaluate != 'undefined') {
  var xpathResult = xmlDoc.evaluate(path, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
  var node;
  while ((node = xpathResult.iterateNext()) != null) {
   console.log(node.nodeValue);
  }
}
```